# In openssh is it possible edit ssh/ssh_config or sshd_config files ciphers wise?

Tags: ssl, openssl, openssh, fips, sslv3

In openssh is it possible edit ssh_config or sshd_config files to enable only TLS 1.2 supporting ciphers and disable tls1.1 and below, sslv3 and below so that the SSH connection uses only TLS 1.2 ???

I could achieve something similar to lighttpd by editing the lightpd.conf file.

Thanks!

Comment: SSH != TLS. You have a fundamental misunderstanding here.

Comment: thank you EJP
If I do a " openssl ciphers -v | TLS" I get the list of ciphers supporting TLS1.2 
So I am looking for a way to substitute the generated ciphers in place of the old ciphers. 
Do correct me if i am wrong/ assumed it the opposite way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the crypto algorithms that you want to use in your client and server configurations by using `Ciphers`, `KexAlgorithms` and `MACs` settings.

SSH protocol is not based on TLS and as such it does not support a concept of TLS protocol versions. You have to hand-pick the algorithms that you want to use. Also note that because it is a different protocol from TLS, the same vulnerabilities and weaknesses do not apply to it.

Read your OpenSSH version's manual pages for `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` to see the list of supported algorithms.

Comment: thank you Snap. https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html gives me the list of the cipher suited that are TLS1.2  
Now, is it possible to alter the ciphers list through commands like SSl_CTX or through any other way??

Comment: Which part of "SSH protocol is not based on TLS" you didn't understand?